# Java thread hangs when I add the code to get time difference

Tags: java, date, thread-safety

As part of my code I get time difference between two fields of an object and put it in a Map. Several times per second new payloads are created and this code is run to make new Maps.

```java
if("deliver".equalsIgnoreCase(type) && "COURIER".equalsIgnoreCase(c))
            attributes.put("pickupToDropTime", ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(payload.getPickingAt().toInstant(),payload.getDeliveredAt().toInstant()));
```

The problem is the code hangs after some minutes of running. When I replace the value part with a constant value it runs fine.

I tried using other time related classes but still the same happens

```java
TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(payload.getDeliveredAt().getTime() - payload.getPickingAt().getTime())
```

Comment: Have you tried breaking every call out into a variable on its own line and step through it with a debugger? It's quite difficult to know where the problem occurs when there are 6+ method calls on the same row.

Comment: Are you sure the program is hanging because of this statement? Did you use some `println` statement to check how far your control flow goes? I doubt that this code could be your hanging culprit.

Comment: @Jeppz actually it was a separate method. I cannot have the luxury of a debugger because my code cannot be run on my local machine. I should deploy it to a kubernetes environment and see the logs in kibana.

Comment: @Iman yes replacing this line with something else solves the problem

Comment: try to surround this code with `try-catch` and print the exception if any. It may be that threads are suppressing some exceptions and you don't see it in the console. For example,  it can be NPE when getting time.

Comment: Then, Add the whole method please, the code you have shared is not enough.

Comment: @Hessam you need to look into tests with mocks then, being unable to run some simple tests locally is detrimental to code quality.